# Passing parameters when submitting a form via jQuery in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to do a form submit to my controller through jQuery Ajax.  The following code works for the most part, however, the ThreadId parameter does not get passed.  If I call the controller directly without using jQuery, it gets passed, but when using jquery, I don't see the ThreadId after form.serialize().  WHat would be the easiest way to pass parameters (like ThreadId) to jQuery form post?

ASPX

```
<% Html.BeginForm("AddComment", "Home", new { ThreadId = Model.Id },
   FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "AddComment" + Model.Id.ToString(),
   @onsubmit = "javascript:AddComment(this);return false" }); %>
<%: Html.TextBox("CommentText", "", new { @class = "comment-textbox" })%>
<input id="Comment" type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Post Comment" />   
<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

JavaScript

```
    AddComment = function (sender) {
    var form = $(sender);
    var data = form.serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/AddComment",
        data: data,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

CONTROLLER

```
    [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddComment(string submitButton, Comment comment)
        {
            comment.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            comment.PosterId = LoggedInUser.Id;

            _repository.AddComment(comment);
            _repository.Save();

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return View("Comment", comment);
            }
            else
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ThreadId` parameter is included in the `action` attribute of the form. When you are ajaxifying this form you are posting to `/Home/AddComment` and no longer supplying this parameter. You could do the following to ajaxify it:

```
$('#idofyourform').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        // use the method as defined in the <form method="POST" ... 
        type: this.method,

        // use the action as defined in <form action="/Home/AddComment?ThreadId=123"
        url: this.action,

        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Another possibility is to include the `ThreadId` parameter inside the form as hidden field instead if putting it in the action attribute.

Comment: Thanks! Your're right the action does have the correct URL.  However, for some reason, instead of my AddComment method being called, my Index method gets called.  Still trying to figure out why.

Comment: Nevermind, I was doing form.action, when it should have been sender.action. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Btw, I have 2 buttons within the form and when I was doing it without jquery I used the name attribute on the input button to figure out which button sent the request at the controller end.  Any idea how I can do this with jquery?

Comment: found this: http://blog.donnfelker.com/2010/06/04/aspnetmvc-multiple-buttons-on-aform-jquery/