# MVC 4 - jQuery Ajax Post Full Form Data to Specific Method

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm really curious. Is it possible to have a jQuery Ajax post operation send the entire form data, serialized or not, to a MVC 4 method that has specific parameters with the same names as the form's input IDs while excluding elements that do not match?

MVC 4 Controller Method

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DoWork(string companyName, string firstName, string lastName, string email)
{
    //.. do stuff and return result...
}
```

HTML

```
<form id="MyForm" method="post">
    <input id="CompanyName" name="CompanyName" type="text"/>
    <input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text"/>
    <input id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text"/>
    <input id="Email" name="Email" type="text"/>
    <input id="Var1" name="Var1" type="text"/>
    <input id="Var2" name="Var2" type="text"/>
</form>
```

jQuery Ajax

```
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
dataType: 'html',
url: '/Controller/DoWork',
data: $('#MyForm').serialize()
});
```

If it's not possible out of the box, does anyone have some basic ideas that I could look into on how to make this happen? I would like to make it 'harder' for someone to figure out my method calls without giving them the exact parameter names and values that are required to make the method work.

Comment: Can be you be a little bit more specific about the part where you said: "while excluding elements that do not match"?

Comment: If you notice in the html there are two extra inputs named Var1 and Var2. Those would not get 'processed' when invoking the controller method since there are no parameters with the same names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a jQuery Ajax post operation send the entire
>   form data, serialized or not, to a MVC 4 method that has specific
>   parameters with the same names as the form's input IDs while excluding
>   elements that do not match?

Yes it is possible. But you remember that you can still access those posted data via the `Reques` object. You can actually remove all the arguments in your controller method and you can still post data to it. The real benefit of having arguments in a controller method is if the type of the argument is an object - a viewmodel. A viewmodel that has dataannotations so you can do validation. But take note that **it is not required**, it's just a technique.

Another thing to note is if you have something like

```
public ActionResult DoWork(string first, string last, int id, int? id2) {
}
```

and you only pass data for `first` and `last` your post action will cause an exception. The exception will be on the `id` parameter that the controller expect to receive a value. Now if you pass values to `first`, `last` and `id` arguments but leave out `id2`, then no exception will occur as `id2` will have a null value.

So your posted example will work. And you can get the values of `Var1` and `Var2` by doing `Request["Var1"]` and `Request["Var2"]`, if you wishes to get their values. You can ignore them of course.

Comment: I understand and in this case the controller method is not a viewmodel. But by removing the parameters it makes unit testing a bit more like WebForms. I am wanting to keep the parameter names and have them mapped to the post data, preferably without doing anything.

Comment: So what is the issue then? Please read my answer again, I may have updated it when you made your comment. I quoted your question and I believe that's what you were asking. Are you asking another thing? Did I misundertand all or any part of your question?

Comment: I am not looking to utilize the Request object. And in my code example the ajax post will fail with an ajax error. Basically the code I posted above does not work.

Comment: "I am not looking to utilize the Request object" that's why I said you can ignore them. I was just explaining how it works. Please post the error you got.

Comment: After looking into it, you are correct. The data does post and map to the fields. The problem I am running into now is that I have added the ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute to the method and that is causing a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh I hope you didn't resort to using the accepted answer here as the way to do it. This question is actually a duplicate, and the and the answer here is the preferred way of doing what you want:
[Passing parameters when submitting a form via jQuery in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005639/passing-parameters-when-submitting-a-form-via-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Looks pretty much like the same thing to me. I will agree the question is a duplicate. But if you think that the accepted answer is wrong then please explain why it is wrong and why your answer is the more preferred way of doing it.

Comment: You are right of course, I failed to state a reason The real problem  with the accepted answer is that it forces you to manually do all of the model binding, type conversion and that defeats the purpose of MVC. Just receive the model, an extra parameter and let the MVC model binder do all of the work for you... always, always always strive for clean code.