# Passing form data to a controller method using Ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Experts,

I have form data -

```
var formdata = JSON.stringify($('#emailrequest').serializeArray());
```

and a url -

```
var urlofRequest = window.location.href;   //This url is of above Emailrequest form .
```

My question is -

How do we send these two - `formdata` and `urlofRequest`  to a .cs(controller) method -

```
 public JsonResult ProcessEmailrequest()
         {
             // What code and parameters?
         }
```

The controller method which opens up the form is -

```
public ActionResult EmailRequest()
{
    return View();
}
```

I have the below code but it does not seems to work -

```
$.ajax({
              url: sitePath + 'supply-chain-pressure/ProcessEmailrequest',
              type: 'GET',
              data: formdata,
              sucess: function (data) {
                  alert('DataPosted');
              }

              })
```

Comment: the data should be fine.  I would recommend using @Url.Action("Action", "Controller") to point to a controller method.  if you want to pass the url you should add it to your formdata object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type in the ajax call is GET; no data is being posted to the form.  Try making it a post or put. [example jquery ajax post](http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-form-submit) Also keep in mind that you are posting form data, so you will need to have parameters on the post method `ProcessEmailrequest` on the `supply-chain-pressure` controller to catch the data. [example of mvc post method](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639709/Getting-Data-From-View-to-Controller-in-MVC)  This is a jquery/ajax example that does basically the same thing [jquery/ajax example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005639/passing-parameters-when-submitting-a-form-via-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: thanks , Can you also direct me to some documenattion which helps in posting data back from server to controller method

Comment: Get data from jquerry call.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198136/how-to-get-data-from-asp-net-mvc-controller-to-jquery-dynamically

Comment: There is also signal R http://signalr.net/,       http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc